# IBM Watson assistant facebook integration issue

Tags: websphere, chatbot, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

Two days ago I successfully did the integration of facebook messenger for the chatbot created in watson and was working with my own FB account only as it wasn't live yet which I understand.

I chose it to be live and now it's not working not in other accounts nor mine, not sure what's the cause of the problem but I checked in watson's dashboard and it reads no integrations and moved FB messenger to "saved" , I even tried to create a new integration with no hope.

Any idea what's going wrong here ?
[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJpb8.jpg)

[Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5cF4e.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I guess the best way to create that is follow link

[Integration Facebook and IBM Watson](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant?topic=assistant-deploy-facebook)

then u should be able to test your bot on the facebook site

some times to be able to do that, facebook ask you to fill to much info about the profile of the page that you are inserting watson, make sure that facebook give you the access for deploy that.